# What are the next two items?

Tags: sequence

```
|=|, |=|, -|, |=, |=, |-|, =|, ..., ...
```

What are the last two symbols in this sequence?

Sorry for being so unclear. There's how I'd draw those symbols:

> [image]

The pic is just for analogy, you still should end the original sequence, not this one.

Hint:

> Duplication (first and second, forth and fifth) is not something you should look at in first place (not the primary logic).

Hint 2:

> You meet these symbols in everyday life.

Hint 3:

> Try to draw all the symbols on the paper, without spaces inside each symbol (i.e., each symbol with one solid line)

Comment: Does "last" actually mean "last"? That is, with those two symbols added is the sequence *complete*, or could it be continued on further? (Feel free not to answer; but if you intended "last" as a hint then it would be nice to know.)

Comment: @Gareth Nice question; the sequence could be continued, though probably not uniquely.

Comment: The hints have been updated, anyone?

Comment: so this sequence(7+2 symbols) is unique, and after 9 symbols it can be continued not uniquely?

Comment: @smriti Sort of, but after it's arguable, so I didn't require more than two symbols.

Comment: Only one solid line for the third item in the sequence?

Comment: @paste The puzzle has been solved.

Comment: @nicael According to the answer, shouldn't the sixth item be `|_|` instead of `|-|`

Comment: @paste I've used `|-|` for analogy - you move other parts, so you'll do that with this symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> the top halves of digits from 9 downwards on a 7-segment display

so the next two are, in the notation used here,

> =|, |.

Comment: Yeeeey! That's great, it wasn't that clear without a pic...

Answer (score 3):

My guess is: **=| , |-**

I think the sequence goes like: 2 same symbols, one unique, 2 same, one unique, 2 same, one unique.

Since the next have to be the same as the previous i just copy it. And the next i assume is this one |- because it's the opposite of the first unique element and they both completes to |=|.

Comment: Interesting, but it's not the rule the sequence follows (I didn't even think of that repetition).

Comment: Eh, I was sure the duplication matters :) So about to the third hint - does this mean I should draw the double horizontal lines (=) as one thicker line, and the single line as one thinner?

Comment: I've clarified the question :)